# Run a FastCGI script without a Web server (for testing)

Tags: command-line, unix

I need a command line utility to test a FastCGI script.

I have an unexpected behavior of our FastCGI script and need to check whether for this behavior is responsible one of our Web servers (two servers chained through a proxy) or the FastCGI script itself.

So I need to run the FastCGI script without the servers.

Well, maybe you can advise how to start either Apache or Nginx without root privilegies with minimal (fully controlled by me, not dependent on the `/etc/` folder) configuration, to test the FastCGI without disrupting our real server.

FreeBSD. It should work without root access.

Comment: "Any script that works correctly as a FastCGI script will also work correctly when installed as a vanilla CGI script. However it will not see any performance benefit." It seems to mean that I can test it as if it would be a regular CGI script.

Comment: Does you CGI script have any external dependencies, server/environment variables? What does your script output? What language is your script written in? For example, Python comes with it's own HTTP server that is suitable for testing.

Comment: @MrWhite It has many external dependencies, I know no special env variables for this script. The script outputs a complex Web page. Perl.